# How to rescale, displace and combine two graphics with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, tikz-styles

I need to create to graphics with TiKZ, on inside the other. The first bigger graphic, is made by plotting some data points. The smaller graphic is some semi-circle with some vectors, which I want to place at the left bottom (empty space) of the big graphic. I originally created the two graphs independently as I was planning to use them separately but I would now to combine them into one. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \begin{axis}[]
  \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
  };
  \end{axis}

% The code for the second smaller graphic starts here

    %axes
    \draw  [ ->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.1);
    \draw  [ ->] (-1.1,0) -- (1.1,0);
    %The two vectors
    \draw [dotted] [ ->] [line width=0.2mm] (0,0) -- (0.707,0.707);
    \draw [dotted] [ ->] [line width=0.2mm] (0,0) -- (-0.65,0.375);
    %the semicricle 
    \clip (-1.2,0) rectangle (1.,1.);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

When I run my code, the smaller graphic is placed at the origin, according to the original coordinates which is obviously not what I want. Here's a picture of the resulting graphic:
[image]
So I am wondering if there is a way to displace and possibly rescale it, so that I move it around to the empty space?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that you can use the `anchor` key. See pag.369 of [PGFplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Comment: You can place the code for the smaller graphic in a `scope` with a `shift=<coordinate>` option.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `scope` environment lets you move things around, and rescale:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \begin{axis}[]
  \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
      (2,-2.8559703)
      (3,-3.5301677)
      (4,-4.3050655)
      (5,-5.1413136)
      (6,-6.0322865)
      (7,-6.9675052)
      (8,-7.9377747)
  };
  \end{axis}

% The code for the second smaller graphic starts here
\begin{scope}[shift={(2,1.5)},scale=1.33]
    %axes
    \draw  [ ->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.1);
    \draw  [ ->] (-1.1,0) -- (1.1,0);
    %The two vectors
    \draw [dotted] [ ->] [line width=0.2mm] (0,0) -- (0.707,0.707);
    \draw [dotted] [ ->] [line width=0.2mm] (0,0) -- (-0.65,0.375);
    %the semicricle 
    \clip (-1.2,0) rectangle (1.,1.);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image: Use of scope in tikz]